# Find the formula for the partial sum of a series from its corresponding sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

If I know that $a_{n}=f(n)$, is there any reliable means of finding a non-recursive equation for the partial sum from 1 to some n?

Comment: In general, no. Do you have a specific series in mind?

Comment: The answer is no since your function is $C^\infty$ howerever if you function is a Polinomial the series will be divergent.

Comment: There is no general method. There are methods for certain restriced classes of functions $f(n)$, such as polynomials.

Answer (score 1):

See e.g. "Gosper's algorithm" in the case of hypergeometric terms for which the sum can be expressed as $S(n) - S(0)$ where $S(n)$ is a hypergeometric term.